# Why does the first footnote display as the second?

Tags: formatting, footnotes, lncs

I'm writing in the Springer LNCS format, and I added a footnote to the caption of a figure:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{INSTITUTE} \\
\maketitle 
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Beta.eps}
\caption{When $m=k=6$, and $500$ samples of $\mathbf{X}$ are generated from the bimodal distribution, $Beta(0.5,0.5)$, $\mathcal{L}_{co}$ fluctuates so drastically that in about half of the $20$ simulations, the MDL approach would miss the causality between $\mathbf{X}$ and $Y$ and leads to the wrong conclusion. $(\mathbf{X},Y)$ purely confounded by $Beta$ sources, on the other hand, work well with the CoCa model.\footnotemark} 
\label{Fig.2}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{https://github.com/PawinData/CoCa}
\end{document}
```

It's the only footnote in the article, yet somehow it displays as the 2nd in the pdf output. Why is that? How can I fix it?

---

Problem solved by @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Use `\caption[abcdefg]{abcdefg\footnotemark}` to avoid that the mark wanders in the listoffigures.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.@UlrikeFischer

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as a solution, you should generally use this syntax. I can't offer an advice for your problem as you didn't provide a complete example that would allow to reproduce it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right. I just editted the post and provide a MWE. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The class processes the caption twice if it is longer than one line. You will have to reset the number before the caption (`\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}`)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Since you provide only code fragment, we haven't information about your document (in form of small complete document, which reproduce your problem) and consequently we are not able to test it and see what can be a problem.

However, your code fragment has some issues:

- label of figure had to be after `\caption{...}`
- `\footnotemark` had to be "protected": `\caption{abcdefg\protect\footnotemark}`

**Edit (1):**
Considering aforementioned the MWE (Minimal Working Example) can and `llncs` document class is:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Beta.eps}
\caption{abcdefg\protect\footnotemark}  % <---
\label{Fig.2}                           % <---
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{https://github/com}
\end{document}
```

which (still) gives correct result:

[image]

**Edit 2**
Apparently you have between `footnotemark` in caption and `\footnotetext` one more `\footnotemark` (or `\footnote`), which cause your problem. It can be eliminated by inserting `\footnotetext` immediately after `figure` before the next `\footnotemark` (or `\footnote`} in text.

Comment: Thank you, Zarko! Your codes did work. I applied the two corrections as you suggested, and the problem was still there. The only difference is `\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}`, I think. Does it matter that I use the Springer LNCS format?

Comment: @PawinData, so far you not inform us anything about your document. Some document classes heavily interfere with default features of `article` class. I will look, what is going on with use of the your document class (I'm afraid that I need to install it first.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned in the message but didn't include in the code chunk. I'll put up a MWE here.

Comment: @PawinData, also with using `llncs` document document class I get correct result.  This means, that in your document you have after  `figure` one more `\footnotemark` or `\footnote` in text before `\footnotetext`. This cause a mess in `\footnotetext` numbering.

Answer (score 1):

The class defines its own caption processing mechanism. Here's the part that sets the actual caption:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \small
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{{\bfseries #1.} #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    {\bfseries #1.} #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

It sets the caption in a box via

```
\sbox\@tempboxa{{\bfseries #1.} #2}%
```

and then measures whether this box is wider than the current allowable box width. If this holds true, it's *reset* to allow for appropriate line-breaking. This dual setting increments whichever counter is used within the mandatory argument of `\caption[<ToC>]{<main>}`. You'll notice this in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[short caption]{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnotemark\space
    %Nunc id nulla at dui facilisis pharetra non scelerisque mi.% <- Uncomment
  } 
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{https://github.com/PawinData/CoCa}
\end{document}
```

If you add the second line of the `\caption` it spans wider than `\textwidth`, is processed twice and therefore `footnote` is incremented twice. A clean and convenient way to counter this is to step the `footnote` counter within the `figure` environment and use a fixed `\footnotemark[<mark>]`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \stepcounter{footnote}% Increment footnote counter
  \caption[short caption]{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnotemark[\thefootnote]\space
    %Nunc id nulla at dui facilisis pharetra non scelerisque mi.
  } 
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{https://github.com/PawinData/CoCa}
\end{document}
```